# With using htmlagilitypack how can you determine whether URI is file or not

Tags: file, uri, html-agility-pack

For example for this url it does not show it as file

http://www.darty.com.tr/e_commerce/ximg/yeniyil/darty%20garanty%20brosur.pdf

But it is a pdf file. So what i want is simply determine all of the urls which can not be crawled like pdf or doc or docx etc. How can i do that with c# 4.0 and htmlagilitypack ?

Thank you.

Does not recognize as file : http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/61/notshowasfile.png

Comment: What do you mean by "does not show it as file"? It *is* a file.

Comment: Joe white here what i mean : http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/61/notshowasfile.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uri` is part of the base .NET Framework -- this has nothing to do with the HTML Agility Pack.

This also has nothing to do with it being a PDF. The documentation for [`Uri.IsFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.isfile.aspx) says:

> The IsFile property is true when the Scheme property equals UriSchemeFile.

In other words, `IsFile` answers the question, "Is this a [`file://` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)"? Since this is an `http://` URI, the answer is no.

You seem to be confusing URLs with content. A `Uri` is just a fancy string; its job is to *be* a URI, not to go out to the server and ask questions about the content *at* that URL. "Is this a file type I know how to crawl?" cannot be answered by looking at the URL; `http://example.com/articles/123` could be a Web page or a PDF or a text file or a JPEG or any of a thousand other things. You have to do a GET or HEAD request to the server, and look at the returned Content-Type, in order to know what type of content that URL represents.

Comment: so how to head request and determine whether it is page or file ?

Comment: The people who know that answer won't be looking at this question about Uri.IsFile. Try posting a new question.